# I'm not able to access the double data type, FormatException

Tags: asp.net

The error is

> Input string was not in a correct format.

Code:

```
Itemname = txtitemname.Text;
pprice = Convert.ToDouble(txtpprice.Text);

sprice = Convert.ToDouble(txtsprice.Text);
pdealer = txtdealer.Text;
pmode = txtpmode.Text;
```

Comment: What culture are you using, what was the text entered?

Comment: You probably have a currency Char in your textbox? You can only convert numerical data to double. I.E. $5.00 wont convert to 5.0

Answer (score 0):

Usually, this error is tied to fact that you haven't specified culture. Different cultures have different way of writing numbers. For example in my country we use "," as decimal separator instead of invariant "."

```
  var d = 5.5;
  Console.Out.WriteLine(d.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
  // yields 5.5
  Console.Out.WriteLine(d.ToString(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(1029)));
  // yields 5,5 (czech culture)
  d = Convert.ToDouble("5,5", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
  // 55
  d = Convert.ToDouble("5,5", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(1029));
  // 5.5
```

Alternatively (or in combination with specifying culture) you can catch the format exception and handle it somehow.

```
  double d;
  try {
    d = Convert.ToDouble("whatever", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
  } catch(FormatException) {
    // parsing error
    d = -1;
  }
```